# x86_64 Linker Error while building React Native project with react-native-document-picker

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm developing a React Native app that utilizes the "react-native-document-picker" library for handling document selection. I followed the installation instructions and ran pod install to set up the dependencies.

However, when attempting to build the app on iOS using Xcode, I'm getting a series of linker errors as shown below:

```
Linking   react-native-document-picker Pods/react-native-document-picker » react_native_document_picker
⚠️  ld: dylib (/Users/ns12/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/geocamereapp-cfodoziwultcvyclefeqfsufrcpk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-Core/React.framework/React) was built for newer iOS Simulator version (12.4) than being linked (11.0)
⚠️  ld: dylib (/Users/ns12/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/geocamereapp-cfodoziwultcvyclefeqfsufrcpk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Yoga/yoga.framework/yoga) was built for newer iOS Simulator version (12.4) than being linked (11.0)
❌  Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64
┌─ Symbol: _UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass
└─ Referenced from: ___44-[RNDocumentPicker getMetadataForUrl:error:]_block_invoke in RNDocumentPicker.o
❌  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
❌  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've tried searching for a solution but without success. It seems there's an incompatibility issue between React Native libraries and the project's dependencies. How can I resolve this problem and successfully complete the iOS build?

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

In the future, please include pertinent information like RN version, Xcode version, module version, etc.

I can just assume at this point, but, did you install the most recent version into your project? If your RN version is below the required version, you will get this error.

Try installing v8.2.1:

`yarn remove react-native-document-picker`

`yarn add react-native-document-picker@8.2.1`

`cd ios && pod install`